# mpdf how to set the page margins on the version 7?

Tags: mpdf

how is possible to set the margins on the new 7 version?
I want to remove the margins of the pages, setting on 0. In the version 6 I set them into new mPDF( but now I don't know how is possible

on the `6` I used :

```
$pdf = new \mPDF('utf-8', 'A4'.($orientation == 'L' ? '-L' : ''), '', '', $margin_left, $margin_right, $margin_top, $margin_bottom, 0, 0);
```

now?

thanks

Answer (score 6):

mPDF 7 constructor has a signature of

```
\Mpdf\Mpdf::__construct([array $config = []])
```

You need to pass an array of values with appropriate keys, which for margins are `margin_left`, `margin_right`, `margin_top`, `margin_bottom`, `margin_header` and `margin_footer`.

The whole code would then be

```
$mpdf = \Mpdf\Mpdf::__construct([
    'margin_left' => $margin_left, 
    'margin_right' => $margin_right, 
    'margin_top' => $margin_top, 
    'margin_bottom' => $margin_bottom, 
    'margin_header' => 0, 
    'margin_footer' => 0,
])
```

All this and other constructor $config keys is written on the [mPDF constructor documentation page](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/construct.html).